# scanf_s error visual studio

Tags: c++, scanf

`int setN, setN2;
char sign;
scanf_s("do %d %c %d", &setN, &sign, &setN2);`

I'm input "do 1 + 3", for example, and program in vs fall with an error "Unhandled exception at 0x650de541 in disc_II_2_1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xc96ff41e".

P.S. code below get the same result.

```
scanf_s("do %d %c %d", &setN, &sign, &setN2, 8);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I put `%d` for `int` and `%c` for `char`, what's wrong? `%x` the same as `%d`, isn't it?

Comment: Either you changed teh question or I misread.  Either way, it's fine now. Although,  what is `sign2`?  Also, why is there an `8`?

Comment: `sign2` is my fault, it's shold be `sign`. `8` - just number of symbols in `do 1 + 3`, which I'm using for test's. I tried it only as version becouse it's `scanf_s`, not `scanf`.

Comment: `scanf_s` doesn't take a number there either...

Comment: Additionally, the code you posted works fine: http://ideone.com/IYNKuA  You'll have to make a minimal testcase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx):

> Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size
>   to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string
>   control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is
>   passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to
>   the buffer or variable.

and later

> In the case of characters, a single character may be read as follows:
>
> ```
> char c;
> scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
> ```

At the end of that reference, there are also a few examples where you may see that:

- the count argument should appear immediately after the corresponding input
- the count argument should correspond to the maximum number of expected char (or as stated above for a single char, it should be 1)

So, in your particular case you should have:

```
scanf_s("do %d %c %d", &setN, &sign, 1, &setN2);
```